# How can I split a string into multiple parts?

Tags: c++

I currently gather a string via bluetooth to my arduino and the string only has 5 different letters. "HELLO". I now wish to store these individual letters in a string on their own. Right now i have this code:

First I create a single string:

```
String readString;
```

Then I read my BTLEserial which is where I get the value that is being sent to the arduino and i store it in my string:

```
char c = BTLEserial.read();
readString += c;
```

`readString` now has the value "HELLO". Now i want to split it and what I have tried is to do it like this:

```
String stringOne = readString.substring (0,1); //H
String stringTwo = readString.substring (1,2); //E
String stringThree = readString.substring (2,3); //L
String stringFour = readString.substring (3,4); //L
String stringFive = readString.substring (4,5); //O
```

But with this i do not get the correct values in each string.

Appreciate every help I can get! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is 0 indexed, which means that number 5 is out of index. "Hello" should be index valued 0-4 and not 0-5.

Here is a better code to try out:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

String recivedMessage = "";

// Read
while (Serial.available())
{
    recivedMessage += Serial.read();
}

// Print debug
Serial.print("recivedMessage: ");
Serial.println(recivedMessage);


//// Uncomment the row under if you are not sure that the splitting is working
// recivedMessage = "Hello";

// Split
char first  = recivedMessage.substring(0, 1)[0];    // H
char second = recivedMessage.substring(1, 2)[0];    // E
char third  = recivedMessage.substring(2, 3)[0];    // L
char forth  = recivedMessage.substring(3, 4)[0];    // L
char fifth  = recivedMessage.substring(4)[0];       // 0

// Print debug
Serial.print("Cut message: ");
Serial.println(first);
Serial.println(second);
Serial.println(third);
Serial.println(forth);
Serial.println(fifth);
```

}

Comment: Yea i changed that but it is not working very good. I think I need to create another solution without strings and use char instead. Do you have any example? Would appreciate it a lot

Comment: Just change Serial.available() and Serial.Read() to whatever channel(Bluetooth) you are listning to. I have tried this code and its working. If this doesn't work for you then you have a problem with the library or something else. This code is = true; =)

Comment: I just tried it with my BLE and if i use the same type of code i only get numbers and not letters when I try this solution.

Comment: You are getting/reading bytes, thats how serial communication works, or is it binary? Anyway you need to translate it from byte to char and then concat to string. If you lookup that number on a ACSII table you will see every number correlate to that char ex. 80 is A

Comment: Found an easy solution. Just put char before the read, it will cast it as char. Ex.  (char)Serial.Read()

Comment: Seems to work well! I get out the different letters now consistently on their own. However i now face a different issue of course haha. The word i send first starts with a "H" and that prints out to the serial monitor just fine. However 5 seconds later that first letter changes to a "B" but the serial monitor still prints out "H" even though it should change to "B".

Comment: Hey are you Polling as they recommend in library? " It's important to constantly call pollACI if you want to efficiently handle data over BLE. Be sure to include this function at the top of your 'loop' function in your sketch. And as often as possible  "

Comment: What board are you using, Uno, mega, nano?

Comment: I am using a Uno! I fixed it now though. The problem was that the value kept adding onto the result. So i just added a simple function to remove the first 5 letters everytime a new result come in with 5 new letters.

Comment: Awesome! Yeah you are right. I thought it would reset itself every cycle. With Variable = "";  Anyway nicely done!

Comment: Yeah exactly i thought so to that it should reset everytime with the "" of the variable. Anyway thanks a ton for your awesome help! :)

Answer (score 0):

String are the not the recommended way to use with Arduino although try using single parameter instead of two like substring(1) and let me know

```
char data[5];
for(int i=0;i <5 ;i++)
{
 data[i]=Serial.read();
}
char data1=data[0];
char data2=data[1];
```

so on and so forth ..

Comment: Yeah I guess I will need to create a solution without a string. Do you have quick examples I could see codewise? Would appreciate it a ton

Comment: You can simply declare a character array

Comment: ok and how do i get each character in the char? data[0] for the first letter ("H")? data [1] for the second  ("E") etc?

Comment: which Bluetooth library you are using by the way ?

Comment: i am using a adafruit BLE and here is the codeexample: https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-the-nrf8001-bluefruit-le-breakout/nrf-uart-in-detail

Comment: try the above code and let me know also you can take character array in place of character pointers whichever you consider  better.

Comment: That solution will not be optimal though because i only use "HELLO" as an example and sometimes the text will change to something else. The amount of numbers in the text (5) will always be the same though

Comment: would this work for you i can't understand what do you want exactly ??

Comment: will try it! one second

Comment: alright try it and let me know if further help needed

Comment: I get the correct value the first time in the monitor! But once it keeps gathering the data over n over the letter instead turns to this symbol: �
 Any idea why?

Comment: your baud value might be wrong which baud value you are using also try to keep you serial monitor close sometimes serial monitor creates problems

Comment: 9600 baud rate in serial monitor and Serial.begin(9600);

Comment: ok try closing serial monitor and verify values by some other ways like lighting up the leds

Comment: yea could try that but i do not currently have leds at home. if i send numbers instead of letters, would that change anything you think? so instead of 5 letters i send 5 different numbers that i store in 5 different int's?

Comment: Actually, serial monitor create conflicts between the serial connection and produces jibberish characters so you have to find a way to somehow verify it some other way if you don't have led's try some other components

Comment: yeah i do not know how to go at it because my current logic/setup is this: I send values from a phone to my arduino and the value is one word containing 5 different letters. When I recieve this word to the arduino i create "if-statements" and run certain commands if a letter is something. So for example, if the first letter in the 5 letter word i send is "H". I have an if-statement that says `if (data[0] == "H")` run a certain command. But as the data[0] produces jibberish characters after the first time this option will not work

Comment: you have to understand the moment you open your serial monitor the same moment you will start receiving the jibberish character so instead of using the serial monitor why don't you simply execute the commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier if you used a char array. Here's some sample code.

```
char recievedData[100]
int numChars = 0
//Now we are in the receiving loop
recievedData[numChars] = BLTEserial.read()
numChars++
```

Now that you have a character array with all of the members, you can simply use the numChars variable to figure out how much you got from the serial buffer (for example, using it as the upper limit for a for loop).

Comment: And to get the first letter out It gets stored here? recievedData[0]? I think I am missing the last part

Comment: Yes, it starts from index 0 and it will go to the counter - 1.

Comment: Also, you need to go out and learn the basics. Everything I just told you is within the material that you would learn in the first month of an intro to programming class.

Comment: it is weird because if i write it out like this: Serial.println (recievedData[0]); and check the serial monitor i see no letter but only blank space that gets recieved. I should get a "H" from that

Comment: What about when you print index 1?

Comment: Also blank space

Comment: Now i suddently get a "?" sign in a black square triangle

Comment: Is your baud rate correct?

Comment: I have it on 9600 baud in my serial monitor and in my `void setup`i have it on 9600 also looking like this: `Serial.begin (9600);` and `  BTLEserial.begin();`

Comment: Here is my BLE documentation and a code example that i use also: https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-the-nrf8001-bluefruit-le-breakout/nrf-uart-in-detail